# Swift 3 - How declare a typed NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to declare a dictionary with `NSMutableArray<Client>` values.
But the thing is I'm getting an error whichs pointing me remove the `<Client>` part.

```
var mydict: [String:NSMutableArray<Client>] = [:]
```

How is the proper way for declare a typed NSMutableArray

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to keep Foundation (NSStuff, like NSMutableArray) in Swift 3 and not use Swift Array, like `var mydict: [String:[Client]]`?

Comment: @ricardo : If all that you are trying to achieve is pass by reference and not pass by value by using NSMutableArray then consider converting client to class rather than struct and use Swift Array thats will be pass by reference not pass by value

Comment: @Ricardo : Array in swift is implemented as Struct. Hence when you create a array of class objects array in itself gets passed as pass by value that means any operations on the array like remove Object / insert object will not be reflected back to passed array but class objects in array are passed by reference so modifying property of any object in array will persist and be reflected in passed array object as well.

Comment: @ricardo : finally if you want to pass swift array itself as pass by reference (shallow copy) then consider passing it as in out param rather :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableArray` is a heterogeneous container

Comment: I think in obj-c there is a way to point a type of this container like NSMutableArray<Client>

Answer (score 1):

A quick expansion on **Vishal Patel**'s answer:

If you paste this into a storyboard it will fail on none Client types

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Client
{

}

struct NoneClient
{

}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    var mydict: [String:[Client]] = [:]

    override func loadView() {
        let client = Client()
        mydict["xyz"] = [client]

        let noneClient = NoneClient()

        mydict["abc"] = [NoneClient]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDict = [String : [Client]]()
```

Comment: This is not a NSMutableArray, structs are passed by copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write like this `var mydict: [String:[Client]] = [:]`

You can do like this

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

    struct Client
    {

    }
    class MyViewController : UIViewController {

        var mydict: [String:[Client]] = [:]

        override func loadView() {
            let client = Client()
            mydict["xyz"] = [client]
            print(mydict)
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, [Client]  is a struct!! not an object!

Answer (score 0):

You should not to use `NSMutableArray` any more, However you can not achieve pass by ref with `NSMutableArray` Either for `Client`if it is **struct**

Please use like below

```
 var myDict = [String : [Client]]()
```

If you want to pass by ref then `Client` should be a **class** in your implementation not **struct** .

If you want to go with `struct` only  then you need to manually reassign updated Client` to dictionary back

in case of **Class** (Better option)

```
(myDict["key1"] as! [Client]).firstName = "Jon"
```

in case of **Struct**

```
    var clientObjArray =  (myDict["key1"] as! [Client])
    var clientObjArrayFirstObj =  clientObjArray.first
    clientObjArrayFirstObj?.name =  "Jon"
    clientObjArray.remove(at: 0)
    clientObjArray.insert(clientObjArrayFirstObj!, at: 0)
    myDict["key1"] = clientObjArray
```

Note: For example I have added first and 0 Index static

Hope it is clear to you